# Use Check Box and Dropdown in Template to Change Database Values

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django project where the user submits a link, then an admin/moderator has the ability to accept or decline the link. In my models there is an attribute called status that is `Submitted` by default. What I hope to accomplish is an admin page where a moderator can look at all the submitted links and click on a checkbox and then select a value form a dropdown list that will change status to `Approved` or `Denied`, similar to the steps you wold take to delete an entry in Django admin.

Here is my `models.py`:

```
class WebPage(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('Submitted', 'Submitted'), 
        ('Approved', 'Approved'),
        ('Denied', 'Denied'), 
        ('Scraped', 'Scraped'),
    )

    url = models.URLField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    stack = models.ForeignKey(Stack)
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='Submitted')
```

my `views.py`:

```
def admin_tools(request, stack_url):
    context_dict = {}

    stack = Stack.objects.get(url=stack_url)
    context_dict['stack'] = stack

    new_links_list = WebPage.objects.filter(stack=stack, status="Submitted")
    context_dict['new_links_list'] = new_links_list 

    return render(request, 'stack/admin_page.html', context_dict)
```

and finally my html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Submission Type</th>
        <th>Submitted by</th>
    </tr>

    {% for link in new_links_list %}
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><a href="{{ link.url }}"> {{ link.title }} </a></td>
        <td>{{ link.link_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ link.submitter }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

</table>
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: You can add custom admin actions. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) for details.

Comment: Thanks, however it seems that these actions can only be used in the admin  page, could I incorporate them into html templates that users can access?

Comment: So I'm not sure what you're asking. You just need a form.